# Mail() header "FROM: " не работает

Tags: email, php

Всем привет, у меня есть функция:

```
public static function sendEmail($to, $theme, $body){
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Техническая поддержка <support@test.ru>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

        mail($to, $theme, $body, $headers);
    }
```

И когда я отправляю к колонке от кого, всегд имя хостинга(к примеру: lastch**test_pr1_am**hb@astral.beget.ru), и не подставляется знаение которое я указал в хедере, подскажите где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте [это](http://www.php.su/mail) но повнимательнее!

Если читать совсем Лень то вот:

```
public static function sendEmail($to, $theme, $body){
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:  text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $headers .= "From: Техническая поддержка <support@test.ru>\r\n";
    mail($to, $theme, $body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако ничего не поменялось(исходя из вашего пример), и документацию я читал, с её помощью я это и писал.

Comment: тогда меняем тактику, запустите свой скрипт на другом сервере на котором точно всё пашет... И если всё заработает то к Хостеру или к настройкам сервера...

Comment: Либо запустите метод mail из приведённой выше документации на своём сервере, и если ничего работать не будет то это Сервак...